# Why did the Hulk leave?

Tags: plot-explanation, character, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-age-of-ultron

In *[Avengers: Age of Ultron (2015)](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt2395427/)*, near the end of the film, the Hulk goes off on his own in a Quinjet and basically abandons everyone and everything that's going on.. when Black Widow asks him to come back, he doesn't say anything and even hangs up on her.

#### Why did he act this way and leave so abruptly?